# Show that if a continuous unbounded function is compact, then the set itself is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

Let C ⊆ $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if there is a continuous function g : C → $\mathbb{R}$ s.t  f(C) is
unbounded, then C is not compact.

My first guess was to try and prove the contrapositive taking the function from (0,infinity)

Comment: This is the contrapositive of the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces), which states that if $C$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, then $f(C)$ is compact.

Comment: Your first guess to take the contrapositive is a good idea. But looking at a specific interval is not.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $C$ is compact, there exists $x_n$ in $C$ such that $|f(x_n)|>N$, let there exists a subsequence $x_{n_p}$ of $x_n$ such that $x=limx_{n_p}$ since $f$ is continuous $f(x)=limf(x_{n_p})$. This implies there exists $M$ such that, if $n_p>M$, $|f(x_{n_p})-f(x)|<1$ and $|f(x_{n_p})|<|f(x)|+2$ contradiction since $f(x_{n_p})$ is not bounded.

Comment: This is a rather sloppy answer. What is $N$?

Comment: @Thomas: it's clearly meant to be a lowercase n.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Do we now need third party comments to understand  an answer?

Comment: Looks like it. I'm not the one making a fuss about a typo.